# Doing math on begin and end dates in a dataframe when not all rows contain an end date

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm an enormous noob using Python to query an SQL database, parse the results into a series of dataframes and output the results to an Excel sheet (xlsxwriter) with a few calculations performed in the Python code, but I'm having issues with one manipulation. I need to find the difference between dates among rows that have the same identifier, but not every identifier corresponds to both a beginning and an end date. I have data that looks like this, for example:

```
ID   date       other stuff
1    1/01/2018  xxxxxx
2    1/04/2018  xxxxxx
2    1/08/2018  yyyyyy
3    1/14/2018  xxxxxx
4    2/01/2018  xxxxxx
4    2/04/2018  yyyyyy
```

I would like the results to be in a new dataframe that is output to a separate sheet in the same Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `groupby`:

```
df['diff days'] = df.groupby('ID')['date'].diff()
```

OUtput:

```
   ID       date   other  stuff diff days
0   1 2018-01-01  xxxxxx    NaN       NaT
1   2 2018-01-04  xxxxxx    NaN       NaT
2   2 2018-01-08  yyyyyy    NaN    4 days
3   3 2018-01-14  xxxxxx    NaN       NaT
4   4 2018-02-01  xxxxxx    NaN       NaT
5   4 2018-02-04  yyyyyy    NaN    3 days
```